# What are some causes of StageWebView failure?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, apache-flex, stagewebview

In my Flex app for iOS, I use a StageWebView to access a web portal for some of app settings.  Occasionally, rather than showing the loaded portal, the StageWebView goes completely gray:

[image: StageWebView showing all gray]

No error event is dispatched, and the component can still be controlled from ActionScript (location events are dispatched, but the content is still not rendered).  Loading the same web site at other times succeeds--the gray area is correctly filled with my web content.

What are possible causes here?  Memory constraints seem like one option, but I can't find any documentation that the iOS web view will stop rendering rather than simply crash the app.

Comment: I imagine network Latency could trigger some type of timeout causing a failure for the data to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We didn't determine the real root cause, but the proximal cause was loading a page in the background (i.e., before setting the stage property of the StageWebView).

Our best theory on the underlying problem was code run by Javascript onLoad and onReady events which interacted poorly with being rendered offstage.

We resolved the issue by directing to an interstitial page in the StageWebView while the main content page was loading, rather than providing progress info in the Flex app itself.